# "CERT_UNTRUSTED" error in Atom

Tags: node.js, github, ide, npm, atom-editor

When I try to view, update, or download any packages in GitHub's [Atom](https://atom.io/), I receive a "CERT_UNTRUSTED" error. I am behind a corporate firewall.

Is there a way to disable NPM's strict SSL settings inside Atom to allow it to handle packages?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As described [here](https://github.com/atom/apm), Atom's own package manager is called APM. Add the following line to its configuration file "~/.atom/.apmrc" (creating the file if it doesn't exist):

```
strict-ssl = false
```

Comment: In Windows, this is located in: %userprofile%\.atom\.apmrc and you need to create the .apmrc if it doesn't exist.

Comment: @Sawtaytoes use `apm config set strict-ssl false`, it will add *stritct-ssl=false* to the *~/.atom/.apmrc*. And if the file does not existed, it will be created.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using node 0.10.34, this could be the issue https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/8894

Recommend using v0.10.33 for now.